# What is $\dim(\mathcal{C}^1\{[a,b],\mathbb{R}\})$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The polynomial functions of degree $n$ are in $\mathcal{C}^1\{[a,b],\mathbb{R}\}$, so does that mean that it has infinite dimension, since you cannot build an $n$-polynomial function from a combination of $(n-1)$-polynomial functions?

Comment: Yes...but the reason you mention is a little foggy: does "$\;n\,-$ polynomial function" mean polynomial of degree $\;n\;$ ? And even then, the easiest reason is because $\;\{1,x,...x^{n}\}\;$ is linearly indendent for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio. Thanks. That is what I mean, yes.

Comment: Nitpick: This argument only works in the non-degenerate case $b > a$. For $a = b$, the dimension is $1$ and for $a > b$ it might be $0$.